# Pipe to program fails, but runs OK in SSH console

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4, pipe, exim

I'm trying to get Rails 4.1 to receive bounceback emails but it's been really difficult to even get to this point. I can run the command below in an SSH console when logged in as root, but when I put it in my /etc/valiases file, I get a bounceback from the script saying "the following addresses failed".

`runuser -l useraccount -c "cd /home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current/bin && rails runner -e development 'EBlast.receive(STDIN.read)'"`

**/etc/valiases/dev.mydomain.com**

`eblast-bounce@dev.mydomain.com: "|runuser -l useraccount -c "cd /home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current/bin && rails runner -e development 'EBlast.receive(STDIN.read)'""`

I've also tried escaping the double-quotes to no avail.

I need to run as useraccount because the RVM environment variables don't exist for root. Running the 1st command in an SSH console when logged in as root works, but not when exim receives an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I had to do to work around the problem:

1) Move the runner script into its own file as [Todd suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23341351/191741); nested quotes were causing the script to fail to run.

2) Make the file executable; the permissions were already set to 755.

3) Even though exim was using my username to execute the script, the environment variables such as PATH and HOME were not set at all! This caused `ruby` to be an unknown command. This caused many other issues because most of the app relies upon RVM and its gemsets. So I couldn't get ruby to run, much less rails. Even if I were to explicitly call the ruby wrapper, `spring` would break because `$HOME` wasn't set. Just a cascade of issues because the user environment wasn't being set. I also couldn't just issue `su - username -c 'whatever'` because the account that exim was using didn't have authority to use `su`.

---

So the working setup looks like this:

**/etc/valiases/dev.mydomain.com**

```
eblast-bounce@dev.mydomain.com: "|/bin/bash -l -c '/home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current/script/receive_eblast_bounce'"
*: ":fail: No Such User Here"
```

**/home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current/script/receive_eblast_bounce**

```
D=`pwd`

HOME=/home/useraccount

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

if [[ -s "/home/useraccount/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  source "/home/useraccount/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
fi

cd /home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current
./bin/rails runner -e development 'EBlast.receive(STDIN.read)'

cd $D
```

I'm now having problems with ActionMailer using SSL when it shouldn't, and I don't know if that's related to something I did here, but at least it executes the rails script.

Comment: It occurred to me that part of the reason it was doing this to you is that exim doesn't execute a shell such as bash to spawn applications.  It executes the app directly, which is why you have to source the environment files that bash would have done for you as part of its startup process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't doublequote inside of doublequotes without doing some escaping.  Once you start escaping quotes, it can get complicated knowing when you also need to escape other characters as well.  Your example doesn't appear to get too complicated, but I suggest a different method.

IMHO you should create a shell script, for example *eblast-bounce-script*, with the piped commands you want to run.  Then set your alias to:

```
eblast-bounce@dev.mydomain.com: "|/path/to/eblast-bounce-script"
```

Make sure the make the script executable, and runnable by the user that exim will be calling it as.  If you make the script mode 755, owned by root, that should be sufficient.

Comment: eblast-bounce@dev.mydomain.com: "|runuser -l useraccount -c 'cd /home/useraccount/rails_deployments/dev.www/current && script/receive_eblast_bounce'" <<< This failed. It doesn't give me a good reason, it just said "the following address(es) failed:" and shows me the raw email contents.

Comment: I also tried moving all of that script into the receive_eblast_bounce file and just using the file reference in the valiases file like you mentioned, but I get the same result. FWIW the receive_eblast_bounce file is executable.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the runuser command. In SSH I try and run the receive_eblast_bounce when logged in as useraccount, but I get runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted. I'm betting that's what the pipe to program user is getting as well. But how would I get my user environment loaded otherwise?

Comment: It seems the script is never run. Within the script I echoed "WTF" > /home/useraccount/bad.txt and the file is never generated.

Comment: It looks like there's even more to it, I'm dealing with a Bluehost tech support. It seems that exim is using useraccount, except the environment variables (PATH) normally loaded when logging in via SSH aren't present. So ruby cannot load because I'm using RVM to manage rubies, and everything else beyond that point depends on RVM/gemsets.

Comment: Have your script source the files it needs to set the environnment.  You can do that as part of the call to the script, or you can do it in the script itself.